# PL/pgSQL query in PostgreSQL returns result for new, empty table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am learning to use triggers in PostgreSQL but run into an issue with this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checkAdressen() RETURNS  TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
  adrCnt int = 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT INTO adrCnt count(*) FROM Adresse
  WHERE gehoert_zu = NEW.kundenId;

  IF adrCnt < 1 OR adrCnt > 3 THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Customer must have 1 to 3 addresses.';
  ELSE
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'No exception';
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I create a trigger with this procedure after freshly creating all my tables so they are all empty. However the `count(*)` function in the above code returns 1.
When I run `SELECT count(*) FROM adresse;` outside of PL/pgSQL, I get 0.
I tried using the `FOUND` variable but it is always true.

Even more strangely, when I insert some values into my tables and then delete them again so that they are empty again, the code works as intended and `count(*)` returns 0.
Also if I leave out the `WHERE gehoert_zu = NEW.kundenId`, `count(*)` returns 0 which means I get more results with the `WHERE` clause than without.

**--Edit:**

Here is an example of how I use the procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE kunde (
kundenId    int PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE adresse (
id      int PRIMARY KEY,
gehoert_zu  int REFERENCES kunde
);

CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER adressenKonsistenzTrigger AFTER INSERT ON Kunde
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE checkAdressen();

INSERT INTO kunde VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO adresse VALUES (1,1);
```

It looks like I am getting the `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` part wrong. I assumed the trigger would be executed after the first `INSERT` statement but it happens after the second one, although the inserts are not inside a `BEGIN;` - `COMMIT;` - Block.

According to the [PostgreSQL Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-begin.html) inserts are commited automatically every time if not inside such a block and thus there shouldn't be an entry in `adresse` when the first `INSERT` statement is commited.

Can anyone point out my mistake?

**--Edit:**

The trigger and `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` seem to be working all right.
My mistake was to assume that since I am not using a `BEGIN`-`COMMIT`-Block each insert would be executed in an own transaction with the trigger being executed afterwards every time.

However even without the `BEGIN`-`COMMIT` all inserts get bundled into one transaction and the trigger is executed afterwards.
Given this behaviour, what is the point in using `BEGIN`-`COMMIT`?

Comment: If you can put together a simple example with empty tables and the trigger definition that would be useful. I'm guessing the problem is elsewhere. Oh - and you'll probably find life easier if you don't use camelCase identifiers. Stick to lower_case_with_underscores it'll cause less trouble in the long-run.

Comment: looks like you're right. I just recreated only the relevant parts and it works. The problem seems to be caused by other table definitions.

Comment: "*inserts are commited automatically*": that depends on your SQL client (and probably how it's configured). If your SQL tool disables auto-commit, then inserts are only committed when you run `commit`;

Comment: I am using pgAdmin III. Inserts are commited without a `commit;` statement so autocommit must be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You need a transaction plus the "DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED" because of the *chicken and egg* problem.

---

starting with two empty tables:

- you cannot insert a single row into the person table, because the it needs at least one address.
- you cannot insert a single row into the address table, because the FK constraint needs a corresponding row on the person table to exist

---

This is why you need to *bundle* the two inserts into one operation: the transaction. You need the BEGIN+ COMMIT, and the DEFERRABLE allows transient *forbidden database states* to exists: it causes the check to be evaluated at commit time.

Comment: I am aware of the problem, it's the reason I used DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED in the first place. It just looks like there is no difference between using BEGIN-COMMIT and omitting it in Postgresql. The trigger does not complain in both cases. It does without DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem a bit silly, but the answer is you need to stop deferring the trigger and run it `BEFORE` the insert.  If you run it after the insert, of course there is data in the table.

As far as I can tell this is working as expected.

One further note, you probably dont mean:

```
RAISE EXCEPTION 'No Exception';
```

You probably want

```
RAISE INFO 'No Exception';
```

Then you can change your settings and run queries in transactions to test that the trigger does what you want it to do.  As it is, every insert is going to fail and you have no way to move this into production without editing your procedure.

Comment: My assumption was that since I am not using a `BEGIN`-`COMMIT`-Block each insert would be commit on its own with the trigger being executed afterwards every time. But even without the such a block all inserts are being bundled into one transaction. Therefore I am wondering what the use of `BEGIN`-`COMMIT` is.

Comment: @TillS, not really.  Everything in PostgreSQL is in either an explicit or implicit transaction.  If only one statement, that statement, plus triggers fired by it, are in the same transaction.  Consequently any of your exceptions will cause the transaction that does the insert to abort.

Now one thing not clear here is that I think you actually want to see the row you are trying to insert, so AFTER is probably what you want.  I don't know you need to defer it.  Note that if you defer, you do an insert and then delete the row, it will fail because it won't find the row and will roll back.